# npm package version and angular version compatibility

Tags: angular, npm, package, version

I am upgrading my application of angular version, and I need to know if upgrading an npm package or not because I am upgrading from Angular 8 to Angular 9.

If for instance I do have installed in my package.json "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4"

How do I know which version of @testing-library/jest-dom matches Angular 9?

Answer (score 0):

You kinda don't, although they try be backwards compatible and Angular, at least at these later stages, usually is.

Try `ng update` to see which Angular dependancies you can update. `npm update` does something similar but actually updates the packages whereas the ng one just tells you which ones can update.

As for third party dependancies, check their docs or trial and error. Use version control, start from a clean point, then just update it and see if anything breaks.